# extjs 3.2 horizonatal scrollbar for grid panel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

2 version, I want to display horizontal scroll bar for grid panel. Grid-panel is binded to panel, and in turn panel is binded to Viewport. I tried using auto-scroll property of grid-panel, but it didn't worked for me. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add: `style:"overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x: scroll;",` to the container of your grid